# How to check if a Google Map Api file is already pushed in blade Laravel

Tags: laravel, google-maps

i have added a google map script file in master blade

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{env('GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY')}}&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>
```

and i @yield another blade which contain same map script but diifrent callback 'initMap'

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{env('GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY')}}&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
  async defer></script>
```

i need to remove first script and push second script, whenever i @yield the required blade.

How can i popout unrequired script and push required script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the script file from your blade as per your requirement and not in master blade.

In your master blade, do something like this
@yield('custom-javascript')

and in your blade file,do something like this
@section('custom-javascript')
    ...here goes your path of script file
@endsection

Comment: i need to use it in master blade for initAutocomplete function @varun.kumar